# Computing largest increase between 10 integers without using a list

Tags: python, list, iteration

I a problem set that I need to solve but am having trouble visualizing how to tackle this problem with the tools I know of currently. Can someone please provide some guidance on how I should tackle this?

Problmem Set:

```
Design a program to compute the largest increase that occurred in a list of 10 numbers. Note: Your design cannot assign a separate variable per number nor can you use a list.

The program should read any 10 integers and print a result: 

Numbers : 48 54 49 47 62 64 79 80 82 84

Largest increase of 15
from 64 to 79
occurred between day 6 and day 7
```

In my mind - I would've tackled this by converting the Numbers into a list and iterating through the list to compare the difference between days. If the difference of the next set of days is greater than the previous set of days, it would replace that value.

From there I would input the final value of my iterations in  `Largest increase of ____` .

However..since I cannot use a list, I'm not entirely sure how to tackle this.

Comment: There is little difference between iterating over numbers in a list and iterating over numbers as they are read. Just have a variable that keeps track of the previous day's variable.

Comment: 62 - 47 also gives a diff of 15. Would you need both pairs (equal to 64 and 79)?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The above was just an example, the numbers were changed but overall it should just be one set of numbers that have the highest increase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use iterators instead of lists, for example:

```py
from itertools import tee


numbers = [48, 54, 49, 47, 62, 64, 79, 80, 82, 84]
a, b = tee(numbers)
next(b, None)

maxnum, argmax = max(map(lambda x: (x[1][1] - x[1][0], x[0]), enumerate(zip(a, b))))
print(maxnum, (numbers[argmax], numbers[argmax + 1]))
```

Output:

```
15 (64, 79)
```

To solve the problem the following are used:

- python built-in functions

  - `enumerate` for iterating through count and values
  - `zip` for aggregating values of multiple iterators
  - `map` for applying a function to every item of iterator
- module `itertools` and "Itertools Recipe" with `tee` function for iterating through pairs, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
- tuple comparisons in `max` function. Comparison of tuples `(increas, increase position)` is used to get the last largest increase.